# reproducible random number series

Tags: php, random

How can i get a series of reproducible pseudorandom numbers in PHP?

In older versions of PHP i could do that just by using the same seed in the [RNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation), but it does not work anymore since PHP has changed the way rand and mt_rand works.

Please also see this comment in PHP.net page:

> Keep in mind that the Suhosin patch which is installed by default on
>   many PHP-installs such as Debian and DirectAdmin completely disables
>   the srand and mt_srand functions for encryption security reasons. To
>   generate reproducible random numbers from a fixed seed on a
>   Suhosin-hardened server you will need to include your own pseudorandom
>   generator code.

link of that comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php#102636

Is there any solution ready? I do not have the time nor the experience to create my own pseudo-random generator code.

My goal is to have a code

```
<?php
   //( pseudo random code here...)
   $the_seed = 123; // 123 is just a number for demo purposes, NOT a static number
                    //...i hope you get the idea. It's just a hardcoded seed,
                    // it could be a seed based on a user-id, a date etc...
                    // we need the same output for a given seed.
   //( pseudo random code here...)

   // ...and finally
   echo $the_random_number;
 ?>
```

so everytime i visit this page i should get the same number.

Comment: [Just set `$the_random_number` to 9.](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/)

Comment: i asked for pseudo-random, not static number. i think its 100% clear.

Comment: I think `$the_random_number` should be 8

Comment: You said 'everytime i visit this page i should get the same number'. How is that different than static?

Comment: i'm going to update the details so you geniuses don't have to emulate the stupidity

Comment: Your definition of random is broken

Comment: @PaulCroarkin The difference is that he won't have to store hundreds, thousands, or millions of pieces - they can be generated on the fly.  He isn't interested in only the first number returned from the prng, he is interested in having many numbers without having to store them.

Comment: @Sharky: Clearly you missed the joke I was making.

Comment: @Adam Davis  Thank you sir, that's the case

Comment: @CanSpice Should have linked to the [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/221/) strip instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Mersenne Twist is a nice fast PRNG and here's a public domain PHP implementation for it:

http://kingfisher.nfshost.com/sw/twister/

That only works on PHP 5.3.0 and above.

Comment: Thank you sir, i'm going to try it right now... i ll accept the answer as soon as i m able to :)

Comment: Also would like to add this implementation for PHP < 5.3.0   http://boxrefuge.com/?p=18

(just found it & test it works like a charm - also interesting article on performance, check it out)

Comment: Why not use the Built in PHP random functions?

Comment: @McKay The second paragraph of the question answers your question.  In short he needs the same sequence of random numbers for a given input - this is usually accomplished by seeding the random number generator with the same seed each time.  However, a common security patch for PHP removes the ability to seed the random number generator because too many people were using it for cryptography applications, but not using a cryptographically secure seed source.

Comment: the boxrefuge.com implentation is not correct (doesn't produce same results as reference implentation)

Answer (score 7):

One of the best random number algorithms by some metrics is Mersenne Twister.
You can find a pure PHP version [here](http://kingfisher.nfshost.com/sw/twister/) (there are others).

You can then call:

```
init_with_integer($integer_seed)
```

and get the same output (for a given seed) every time.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need a high quality output, the [Lehmer RNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_random_number_generator) is about as simple as it gets. It was one of the algorithms could have been used by `srand()` internally (depending on your operating system).

```
$seed = 42; // any integer, maybe a database id

// init Lehmer RNG
$seed = $seed % 2147483647;
if ($seed <= 0) $seed += 2147483646;

// generate as many random numbers as you need
$seed = $seed * 48271 % 2147483647;
print($seed);

$seed = $seed * 48271 % 2147483647;
print($seed);

$seed = $seed * 48271 % 2147483647;
print($seed);

$seed = $seed * 48271 % 2147483647;
print($seed);
...
```

You can constrain the output to a range with:

```
$min = 0;
$max = 9;
print($min + ($seed % $max));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not best one but it is a work one

```
function ranseed($min, $max, $seed) {
    return round($min + (hexdec(md5($seed)) / hexdec("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF")) * ($max - $min));
}
```